# Recreating a square with fixed baseline and height (3d)

Tags: best-practices, 3d

I am trying to recreate the following image, as close as possible.

[image: examsuqare]

The point is that the circumference of the bottom, plus the height of the cube needs to be 30. Which gives

30 = 4x + h

so I want to be able to draw the cube where I vary the value of x. Below is what I have done so far

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\pgfmathsinandcos[3]{% 
  \pgfmathsetmacro#1{sin(#3)}% 
  \pgfmathsetmacro#2{cos(#3)}% 
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathsetmacro\AngleFuite{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro\coeffReduc{.3}
\pgfmathsetmacro\clen{2}
\pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{\AngleFuite}

\begin{scope} [x     = {(\coeffReduc*\cost,-\coeffReduc*\sint)},
               y     = {(1cm,0cm)}, 
               z     = {(0cm,1cm)}]

\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{5} \pgfmathsetmacro{\h}{30-4*\x}

\path coordinate (A) at (-\h/2,\x/2,\x/2) 
      coordinate (B) at (-\h/2,-\x/2,\x/2)
      coordinate (C) at (-\h/2,-\x/2,-\x/2)
      coordinate (D) at (-\h/2,\x/2,-\x/2)
      coordinate (A1) at (\h/2,\x/2,\x/2)
      coordinate (B1) at (\h/2,-\x/2,\x/2)
      coordinate (C1) at (\h/2,-\x/2,-\x/2)
      coordinate (D1) at (\h/2,\x/2,-\x/2)
      coordinate[label=$h$,left=0.65em] (M1) at ($ (B)!.5!(C) $)
      coordinate[label=$x$,below=2em] (M2) at ($ (C1)!.5!(C) $)
      coordinate[label=$x$,below=1.75em] (M3) at ($ (C1)!.5!(D1) $);

\fill [blue, fill opacity = 0.2]   (A)--(B)--(C)--(D) -- cycle;
\fill [blue, fill opacity = 0.3]   (C)--(D)--(D1)--(C1) -- cycle;
\fill [blue, fill opacity = 0.2]   (A1)--(B1)--(C1)--(D1) -- cycle;
\fill [blue, fill opacity = 0.2]   (B1)--(C1)--(C)--(B) -- cycle;
\fill [blue, fill opacity = 0.1]   (A1)--(D1)--(D)--(A) -- cycle;

\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (A) -- (A1) -- (B1) -- (C1) -- (D1) -- (A1) ;
\draw (B) -- (B1) ; \draw (C) -- (C1) ; \draw (D) -- (D1) ;

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

My main problem, is that the code is very messy. And still does not quite do what I want it do do. I still having problems rotating the cube properly,
The backlines are not shaded, and the whole coordinate thingy seems very messy and unproffesional. A tad smaller figure would also be much appreciated, I tried scaling the whole image, but alas this also shrank the labels.

Any tips suggestions to a better code, or ways to improve mine?

[image: my attempt]

Answer (score 3):

run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\psset{Decran=15,viewpoint=20 20 50 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\multido{\iX=1+1}{7}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,13)
\psSolid[object=parallelepiped,
         a=\iX,b=a,c=30 a 4 mul sub,
         rm=0,incolor=blue!40,hollow,
         fillcolor=red!80,
         action=draw**]
\rput[r](5,5){\huge$x=\iX$}
\end{pspicture}
\clearpage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There are times when `pstricks` seems to do things very easily. This one is a *great* example. Thanks. Oh, and +1